# Importing Java Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import

i know this will be pretty straight forward but i  cant do it   even after doing  lot of Google search  ..  i am downloading  projects from [Planet-source-code](http://www.planet-source-code.com/)  and then  modifying them  for learning purpose  .
Problm is that when i download files  and unzip them  folder contains  `.java .jar images and other resources`    but when i  `import complete folder`  this is result

[image]

Please guide me how to  import complete projects with all resources , i found official link here  [Importing existing projects](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm)
 but that did not work , please help

Comment: Did you unzip the project in `..\j\New Folder` ?

Comment: Can you share the link to the zip file you downloaded ?

Comment: this one  http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=3606&lngWId=2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [zip file](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=3606&lngWId=2) don't contain a java project. Unzip the zip file. In eclipse create a new Java project (a blank project). Then copy the `DieRoll.java` file from the unzipped folder in your eclipse project.

Comment: ok i did  paste .java file in  src folder that works(+1)  . but it does not seem to be standard practice .am i right ?

Comment: Actually the site didn't shared the `project` exactly. They just extracted the code (`.java` file) and some other files and zipped them.

Comment: ok , thank u for your help  ,so if they had shared complete project  i could have imported project  in this way  as i mentioned in question ?

Comment: Yes, you can import a project that way.

Answer (score 2):

when you import existing project into work space mean you have to extract the project in outside the work space folder then choose it ,if you extract the project in same work space mean you will get conflict ,that's reason for your error

Answer (score 0):

This zip file don't contain a java project. Unzip the zip file.Then do as follows.

[image]

see here you can import from here.After clicking on import you can select file type.